# Getting selected value from a dropdown menu django

Tags: html, django, drop-down-menu, django-views

I currently have a dropdown menu from which i want to get the chosen element from a user. 
**How can I return the element to the views.py?**

I would like to keep the same visual but I can use any types of form ,option,select that could help me.

```
   <div id="tableDiv" class="dropdown">
        <button id="tableButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle"  type="button"
          data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                   Rank
         <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul id="tableMenu" class="dropdown-menu"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Att1</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Att2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Att3</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

thanks

Comment: I think what I'm referring to is an ajax request

Answer (score 0):

**Template : dropdown_menu_form.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'dropdown_menu_form' %}" id="dropdown_menu_form">
<select name="dropdown_menu_option" form="dropdown_menu_form">
  <option value="Att1">Att1</option>
  <option value="Att2">Att2</option>
  <option value="Att3">Ope3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
path('dropdown_menu_form/', views.dropdown_menu_form, name='dropdown_menu_form')
```

**views.py**

```
def dropdown_menu_form(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
  selected_value = request.POST.get('dropdown_menu_option')
  #do something
 else :
  template = 'app_name/dropdown_menu_form.html'
  return render(request, template)
```

Comment: this would indeed return the value to the view.py but would do also change the visual of the dropdown button which I dont want, as well as rendering a new url (which i could specify to be the same but i actually want to stay at the same level on the current page)